# Can't change state of a button in Tkinter Python 3.x

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-button

Im creating an app where there is a window that opens another window.
While this happens i want to set the state of the buttons that initialize this procedure as DISABLED but i keep getting this error.

```py
def main():

    def modify():
    
        mods.config(state=DISABLED)
        dell.config(state=DISABLED)
        close.config(state=DISABLED)
    
        while True:
                    
            errorbox.destroy()
            win = Replacy(self,dbn,self.coln,self.it,client,tree,item)
            win.resizable(False,False)
            win.grab_set()
                    
                    
            break
    
        mods.config(state=NORMAL)
        dell.config(state=NORMAL)
        close.config(state=NORMAL)
    
    def delete():
    
        mods.config(state=DISABLED)
        dell.config(state=DISABLED)
        close.config(state=DISABLED)
    
            def deldel():
    
                tree.delete(item)
                eeeeerrorbox.destroy()
                coln.delete_one(self.it)
                errorbox.destroy()
    
        eeeeerrorbox = Tk()
        eeeeerrorbox.geometry("255x80")
        eeeeerrorbox.title("Error")
        eeeeerrorbox.iconbitmap(False,fold +"/info.ico")
                
        l2=Label(eeeeerrorbox,text='Are you sure you want to delete this entry?')
        l2.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=3, pady=(7, 10),padx=10, sticky="w")
                
        dellll = ttk.Button(eeeeerrorbox,text="Yes",command=deldel,width = 7)
        dellll.grid(row=1, column=0,columnspan=2)
        closeee = ttk.Button(eeeeerrorbox,text="No",command=eeeeerrorbox.destroy,width = 7)
        closeee.grid(row=1, column=2)
        eeeeerrorbox.resizable(False,False)
        mods.config(state=NORMAL)
        dell.config(state=NORMAL)
        close.config(state=NORMAL)
        eeeeerrorbox.mainloop()
    
    errorbox = Tk()
    errorbox.geometry("210x80")
    errorbox.title("Error")
    errorbox.iconbitmap(False,fold +"/info.ico")
            
    l2=Label(errorbox,text='How would you like to edit this entry?')
    l2.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=3, pady=(7, 10), sticky="w")
            
    mods = ttk.Button(errorbox,text="Modify",command=modify,width = 7)
    mods.grid(row=1, column=0)
    dell = ttk.Button(errorbox,text="Delete",command=delete,width = 7)
    dell.grid(row=1, column=1)
    close = ttk.Button(errorbox,text="Close",command=errorbox.destroy,width = 7)
    close.grid(row=1, column=2)
    mods.config(state=NORMAL)
    dell.config(state=NORMAL)
    close.config(state=NORMAL)
    errorbox.mainloop()
```

and this is the error i keep getting whatever i try or indenting or placing.

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\\Users\\nagia\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib\\tkinter\__init_\_.py", line 1921, in __call__
return self.func(\*args)
File "g:\\nagia\\Harris\\ProductivityReports 3.0\\history.py", line 65, in modify
mods.config(state=NORMAL)
File "C:\\Users\\nagia\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib\\tkinter\__init_\_.py", line 1675, in configure
return self._configure('configure', cnf, kw)
File "C:\\Users\\nagia\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib\\tkinter_init_.py", line 1665, in \_configure
self.tk.call(\_flatten((self.\_w, cmd)) + self.\_options(cnf))
\_tkinter.TclError: invalid command name ".!button"
```

however if i remove lines 65 66 67 then when the new window appears, the old one with the three buttons gets destroyed as if there is an invisible error but the app doesnt crash as it did before.

Any help is appreciated!!!!

Comment: Methinks you may neeeed a new keeyboard :-)

Comment: There are undefined stuff in your code like `self`, `dbn`, etc.  Since you have used `self`, it looks like the function is within a class, but the function does not have `self` as the first argument.  It is better to provide a [mre].

Comment: Don't use multiple instances of `Tk`, use `Toplevel` instead

Comment: @Thingamabobs Im using tk for a window and toplevel for the other. if a third window has to open i name it tk because the photos crash . its not part of the issue im dealing with here..

Comment: @acw1668 i gave the part of the code that crashes the program. the function itself is a part of a subsclass that worked perfectly before adding the state configs. My question is about only the state crashes and not about the self, dbn and other variables.

Comment: The exception is because you have destroyed the window `errorbox`, so those widgets inside the windows are destroyed as well.

Comment: It is part if the issue, even though you destroy the first instance of `Tk` named `errorbox` the python instances are still available, and they reach out for the new instance of `Tk` named `eeeeeerrobox` to configure a widget that has been part of the previous instance of `Tk`. Deal with it.

Comment: @acw1668 omg you are right. i just noticed that it gets destoryed in the while loop. im working on this project quite a while so im getting lost sometimes. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The exception is because you have destroyed the window *errorbox*, so those widgets inside the windows are also destroyed. @acw1668

I just noticed that it gets destroyed in the while loop.

I just removed `errorbox.destroy()` in the while loop and everything works like a charm

Comment: You don't need the while loop.

Comment: The thing that I fail to understand is why does this affect the procedure. I know that Python is a linear language and I fixed the issue in the current problem. However if I don’t ever call the function aka press the button , the error box will never get destroyed so it should work. Should I use destroy commands and functions below the creation of labels and buttons in order to work?